# Numerical solution to partially-free boundary optimization problem

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, splines

### Background

---

First of all, I'm a PhD physicist working in numerical analysis, so I apologize for possible easy-to-spot mistakes (they're most likely not that easy for me).

The problem I'm trying to solve is to **find the saddle point(s) of an integral functional** $S(z(x,y),\gamma(x,y))$ **on a partially-free, simply-connected, integral domain** $\Omega(\gamma)$:
$$S(z(x,y),\gamma(x,y))=\int_{\Omega(\gamma)}f(z)dxdy,$$
$$\text{find  }(\hat z,\hat\gamma)\text{  such that    }\delta^2S(\hat z,\hat\gamma)=0,$$
where $f$ is given and nonlinear, $\gamma$ is a curve and $z$ is a surface, both of which have some boundary conditions. $S(\hat z,\hat\gamma)$ has a minimum in the $z$ direction, and a generic saddle point in the $\gamma$ direction.

[image]
[image]

For a scientific context, it's the extension of [Coleman's Action for vacuum decay](https://www2.physik.uni-muenchen.de/lehre/vorlesungen/wise_21_22/Neutrino-Mass-and-Grand-Unification/Material/coleman_tunneling.pdf) to the [Witten-Sakai-Sugimoto model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.8858), a holographic theory that can be used to study [cosmological phase transitions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.02579.pdf).

### Trials

---

I am trying to solve this problem using a 2D linear spline for $z$, and a cubic spline curve for $\gamma$, and I'm currently working in MATLAB. To better face the sturdiness of this issue, I tried some more basic cases first:

- I completely solved the fixed-boundary minimization problem with the correct $f$. Fixing $\gamma$ to be any curve (a quarter of ellipse in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkq1J.png) above), my algorithm is capable of finding the correct $z$ that minimizes $S$. I'm planning to use this as the "core algorithm" for the other, more general solutions.
- I wrote an algorithm that varies the curve $\gamma$ minimizing a different functional, with a fixed polynomial $z$, i.e. not found by minimization, and with a much simpler $f$, i.e. just the volume under the surface. It is much slower, but it works.
- The next case already does not converge: trying to minimize the gradient of $S$ instead of $S$ itself (with the same simpler $z$ and $f$), the optimization algorithm takes steps that are either too small or too big. Trying with the original $f$ and with free $z$ (obtained by minimization, like in the first case) would be the next trial, but not having convergence on simpler instances makes me doubtful.

---

> Is there an inherent reason why such algorithms do not converge? Is the cause of the trouble to be imposed on the saddle point/free boundary/nonlinear nature of the problem?

> Are there some known strategies when approaching these problems?